# CSS background image from PHP file

Tags: php, css

I'm trying to set a background in CSS using a PHP file like background:

```
url('images/header-pics/display_header-pics.php') no-repeat;
```

It works when I use:

```
<?php
$img = "3.png";
header ('content-type: image/png');
readfile($img);
?>
```

But if I add a conditional statement nothing is returned.
My code is:

```
<?php
if(is_single() || is_archive())
    {
        $imagePath = "3.png";
    }
    elseif(is_home())
    {
        $imagePath = "2.png";
    }
    else
    {
        $imagePath = "1.png";
    }

    header ('content-type: image/png');
    readfile($imagePath);
?>
```

Comment: the code looks ok and if it's working for your first example it should work in your second. are you sure you're not getting an error caused by one of those functions?

Comment: Do you receive any error ? Activate php display error setting.

Comment: When you open in your browser `images/header-pics/display_header-pics.php` with the 2d version, does it display an image? And +1 to @Klian and @mickadoo.

Comment: Are you sure you defined functions is_single(), is_archive() and is_home()?

Comment: 1. I actually get a 404 page not found when going to /images/header-pics/display_header-pics.php

2. Am I going to define is_single(), is_archive() and is_home()?
I thought these were build in wordpress variables. I'm rererencing them from other php files without any problems.

3. Yes, I'm also puzzled about why the simple example works and it does'nt work with conditional statement.